# Change Background Color For Images.xcassets Images?

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to change the background color of the editors preview of added images. All my images I get from the art team are white. Can I set the background preview of the Images.xcassess screen to be black somewhere?

I dont want to set the default tint of these images to non-white.

[image]

Comment: You can select the image and tape space bar to preview it but i don't think that's possible to change the background color

Answer (score 0):

There is a plug-in for Xcode which take care of that pretty nicely...

TOCAssetCatalogBackground:

https://github.com/toco/TOCAssetCatalogBackground

recommend to install and look for it via Alcatraz - Very simple & very easy.